# Angular post method Type 'Observable<HttpEvent>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Type 'HttpEvent' is not assignable to type 'TestUser'

Tags: angular, post, nestjs

I am trying to use the POST method to save some data to my testserver. (Methods on the server itself are doing their job already)

I want to be able to add User data to seperate input fields and send them with a button the server, so that I can show the stored data with another button. The get method already does the job and shows the test data from my server but I have trouble with post method.

I am getting this message on the addUser() function, even tho I tried to adapt the tour of heroes Post example.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

> TS2322: Type 'Observable<HttpEvent>' is not assignable to
> type 'Observable'.   Type 'HttpEvent' is not
> assignable to type 'TestUser'.     Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the
> following properties from type 'TestUser': id, firstName, lastName,
> isActive

testService.ts

```ts
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {TestUser} from './testUser';
import {catchError, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
    
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {
    
  testUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
    
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    
  getUser(id: number): Observable<TestUser> {
    const url = `${this.testUrl}/${id}`;
    console.log('a');
    console.log(this.http.get<TestUser>(this.testUrl));
    return this.http.get<TestUser>(url);
  }
    
  addUser(newUser: TestUser): Observable<TestUser> {
    return this.http.post<TestUser>(this.testUrl, newUser, this.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

testUser.ts

```ts
export interface TestUser {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  isActive: boolean;
}
    
export const TEST_USER_EMPTY: TestUser = {
  id: 0,
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  isActive: false,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should focus on the last parameter in the post method - this.httpOptions. Unfortunately you did not share with us, how it looks like but looking into the definitions of the HttpClient we see that depending on the passed parameters for the post method it may return different types - one of them is

```
Observable<HttpEvent<Object>>
```

Are you using in the options the following statement?

```
observe: 'events';
```

If not maybe is httpOptions object somehow formatted incorrectly so that angular returns wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your `httpOptions`? If you init it with {} then it would be fine. This worked for me